# How to handle PByte pointer operations in D5/D7 (Operator not applicable to this operand type)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-5

I'm trying to port [`DDetours`](https://github.com/MahdiSafsafi/delphi-detours-library) lib to Delphi 5/7. The lines that wont compile have this pattern:

```
procedure Decode_J(PInst: PInstruction; Size: Byte);
var
  Value: Int64;
  VA: PByte;
begin
  ...
  VA := PInst^.VirtualAddr + (PInst^.NextInst - PInst^.Addr) // <- compiler error
```

with compiler error:

> [Error] InstDecode.pas(882): Operator not applicable to this operand
>   type

`PInst^.VirtualAddr, PInst^.NextInst, PInst^.Addr` are all declared as `PByte` (`PByte = ^Byte`)

What can I do to resolve this?

---

EDIT:

`PInstruction` is defined as:

```
  TInstruction = record
    Archi: Byte; { CPUX32 or CPUX64 ! }
    AddrMode: Byte; { Address Mode }
    Addr: PByte;
    VirtualAddr: PByte;
    NextInst: PByte; { Pointer to the Next Instruction }
    OpCode: Byte; { OpCode Value }
    OpType: Byte;
    OpKind: Byte;
    OpTable: Byte; { tbOneByte,tbTwoByte,... }
    OperandFlags: Byte;
    Prefixes: Word; { Sets of Prf_xxx }
    ModRm: TModRM;
    Sib: TSib;
    Disp: TDisplacement;
    Imm: TImmediat; { Primary Immediat }
    ImmEx: TImmediat; { Secondary Immediat if used ! }
    Branch: TBranch; { JMP & CALL }
    SegReg: Byte; { Segment Register }
    Rex: TRex;
    Vex: TVex;
    LID: TInternalData; { Internal Data }
    Errors: Byte;
    InstSize: Byte;
    Options: Byte;
    UserTag: UInt64;
  end;

  PInstruction = ^TInstruction;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In newer Delphi versions, `PByte` can be used in pointer arithmetic. Before that, the only type that could do that was `PChar` (`PAnsiChar` or `PWideChar`). In Delphi 5, `PChar` is a `PAnsiChar`.

#### Update

Now I know the structure of the record and know what you want to achieve, I think you should probably do the following.

You could change all `PBytes` in `TInstruction` to `PAnsiChar` (or `PChar`, if you only care about D5), and also all `PBytes` in every routine. Then you get:

```
PInstruction = ^TInstruction;
TInstruction = record
  Archi: Byte; { CPUX32 or CPUX64 ! }
  AddrMode: Byte; { Address Mode }
  Addr: PAnsiChar;
  VirtualAddr: PAnsiChar;
  NextInst: PAnsiChar; { Pointer to the Next Instruction }
  ...
end;

...

procedure Decode_J(PInst: PInstruction; Size: Byte);
var
  Value: Int64;
  VA: PAnsiChar;
begin
  ...
  VA := PInst^.VirtualAddr + (PInst^.NextInst - PInst^.Addr);
  ...
```

But note that if you want to read or write a byte using these `PAnsiChars`, you will have to cast them to `PByte`.

Comment: Better to be explicit and use `PAnsiChar` surely, then at least the code will mean the same thing on all Delphi versions

Comment: @David: I agree, but I was not sure if `PAnsiChar` is actually defined in Delphi 5, and if it is, if it can do the same as `PChar`. I haven't used Delphi 5 since, IIRC, 2001.

Comment: It has to be defined there because they have `PWideChar`, `WideString` etc. COM was supported from very early.

Comment: @David: OK, I will edit my answer. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I get an error: `[Error] InstDecode.pas(884): Incompatible types: 'Char' and 'Byte'` changing the line to `PChar(VA) := PChar(PInst^.VirtualAddr) + (PChar(PInst^.NextInst) - PChar(PInst^.Addr))` works. note the `PChar(VA) :=...`

Comment: as I mentioned in my question, all parameters in the original code are `PByte`. I also added the declaration of `PInstruction` in the EDIT.

Comment: Note that in my answer, I had already changed the type of VA to P(Ansi)Char. So there is no need to cast it to PChar anymore. As I said: replace ***all*** PBytes to P(Ansi)Chars and cast to PByte when you must read or write a byte.

Comment: @zig: See my update. Now I know the record and what you want to do with it.  Simply use PAnsiChar instead of PByte, and only cast to PByte is you must access a byte.

Comment: actually in D5 pointer maths was mandatory for every typed pointer, in later Delphi it became optional, but in D5 Pointer math is always on. 

`var i: integer; p: PInteger absolute I;  begin i := 0; Inc(p, 10); writeln (i); end.`

Comment: @Arioch'The: Huh? With "pointer math" I mean adding an offset to a pointer, or subtracting two pointers to get a distance, and all of that scaled by the size of the type to which they point. `Absolute` is not pointer math, and it is, IMO, an abomination that ought to be removed from the language and the face of this earth.

Comment: "adding an offset to a pointer" is exactly what `Inc` procedure does. Granted, in newer Delphi there might be added more Pointer Math features, but some of them already were there in D5

Comment: in soviet pascal for DEC PDP-11 the `absolute` feature was made into a variable name declaration: `var xxx: pointer; yyy origin xxx: integer;` - and it was surely more reasonable than making it part of variable type as in Turbo Pascal. However `absolute` still has one advantage: it is (while inherently unsafe) a DRY-compliant typecast, almost the same as declaring (and assigning) an extra local variable - but without wasting memory and CPU. Comparing to copy-pasting dozens of `type(var)` typecasts all through the function body, the "do it only once" nature of `absolute` looks better

Comment: @Arioch'The: `Inc(pointer, count)` has always worked in all Delphi versions.  What does not work in D5 (except for `PAnsiChar`) is code that uses `pointer + count` directly instead. That was added in D2009 with the introduction of the `{$POINTERMATH}` directive.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: not always in all Delphi versions. But I think it worked in D5 and later versions.

Comment: FWIW: I defined a type especially for pointer arithmetic: `{$IFDEF UNICODE}
  PArithByte = PByte;
{$ELSE}
  PArithByte = PChar;
{$ENDIF}`. One could improve the `IFDEF` condition, I guess. And maybe explicitly use `PAnsiChar`. It only has to work with D2007 and XE6 for me, so I didn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Under Delphi 5, try:

```
procedure Decode_J(PInst: PInstruction; Size: Byte);
var
  Value: Int64;
  VA: PByte;
begin
  ...
  VA := PByte(integer(PInst^.VirtualAddr) + (integer(PInst^.NextInst) - integer(PInst^.Addr)));
```

Using `integer()` typecasting may fix the pointer arithmetic issue. But it will work under 32-bit executables only.

Comment: Thanks, but then I have the same error on `PInst^.Branch.Target := VA + Value` where `Value` is `Int64`. should I change it to `PInst^.Branch.Target := PByte(Integer(VA) + Value);`?

Comment: AFAIR another trick is `integer(VA) := integer(PInst^.VirtualAddr) + .....`.  But take care about "Pointer Math" - it does not matter for PByte/Pointer but it will have effect for PWord, PInteger, etc.